# data binding a listbox control which can be single or multiple value

Tags: java, xpages

On an XPage I have placed a listbox control. The listbox can be single or multiple value, based on a selection on the xpage (via an other control). The listbox data is bound via a managed bean:

```
<xp:listBox id="Country" value="#{employeeBean.employee.countries}" >
<xp:this.attrs>
<xp:attr name="multiple">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(employeeBean.employee.type == "Multi"){
    return "true";
}}]]></xp:this.value>
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{employeeBean.employee.Type eq "Multi"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
</xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>
<xp:selectItems>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Sweden"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Norway"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:listBox>
```

By default the listbox is single value.

When I remove the data binding the switch between single or multiple goes well. When I attach it, it stops working.

I fear my data binding is somehow incorrect:

In my employee class:

```
private List<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
    public void setCountries(List<String> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
```

In my Employee DAO class

load(ViewEntry):

```
if(doc.hasItem("country")){
    employee.setCountries(doc.getItemValue("country"));
}
```

save(Employee):

```
doc.replaceItemValue("country", new Vector(employee.getCountries()))
```

Does anyone has a suggestion how I can solve my struggle? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a listBox single or multi-valued just like that. What you are setting is a HTML property that has no bearing when the value gets set or retrieved. As far as your listBox is concerned what the control is expecting is a simple `String`. It would barely work if: you selected just one value from the list and hadn't *typed* countries as you did. But you did: it's `List<String>`. To make it work as it is you should use the property `multiple`.

`<xp:listBox id="Country" value="#{employeeBean.employee.countries}" multiple="true">`

But it won't give you the flexibility you need. You need to rethink your approach: either custom converter or something else.

Comment: Hello shillem, you are right. I was wrong in my perception that the multiple value can be computed. When I added two additional listbox controls and enabled the multiple property on one I noticed in the DOM that the first listbox (the one with the calculated multiple property) had incorrect values so I assume it was single value in the first place (and always). My 'solution' is now to have two listboxes within a panel and compute the rendered property.

Comment: Also in my DAO class I check what type I have and based upon that I save a normal string value or a vector value. Proabably not the most elegant approach but for now it seems to be working at least. Thank you for your comment, it has been really helpful.